# how to published assertion failure in email alerts through jenkins

Tags: jenkins, report, jenkins-plugins, email-attachments, newman

How to publish this assertion error in post build action in email alerts ? Currenlty only build status is published in email alert using Editable Email notification in Postbuild,

Need the reason also in email alerts

[image: NewmanReport]

Answer (score 0):

Solved by sending the attached logs and path in postbuild action